# Как разнести значение из первых вхождений по повторяющимся вхождениям?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть такой DataFrame:

```
            from           to  incident            check_string  occurrences
npp
1    00001234567  01011234567     12345  0000123456701011234567            1
2    00001234567  01011234567     45678  0000123456701011234567            2
3    00001234567  01011234567     45678  0000123456701011234567            3
4    00001234567  01011234567     45678  0000123456701011234567            4
5    00001234568  01011234568     81289  0000123456801011234568            1
6    00001234568  01011234568     27811  0000123456801011234568            2
7    00001234568  01011234568     27811  0000123456801011234568            3
```

Мне нужно значение `incident` из первого вхождения `occurrences == 1` разнести по повторяющимся вхождениям строки `check_string`, т. е. там где `occurrences > 1`. Повторяющихся строк может и не быть. Я это делаю так:

```py
def distribute(row):
    return df2['incident'][df2['check_string'] == row['check_string']].item()

df2 = df[['check_string', 'incident']][df['occurrences'] == 1]

df['incident_src'] = df.apply(lambda row: distribute(row), axis=1)
```

В итоге получается следующее:

```
            from           to  incident            check_string  occurrences  incident_src
npp
1    00001234567  01011234567     12345  0000123456701011234567            1         12345
2    00001234567  01011234567     45678  0000123456701011234567            2         12345
3    00001234567  01011234567     45678  0000123456701011234567            3         12345
4    00001234567  01011234567     45678  0000123456701011234567            4         12345
5    00001234568  01011234568     81289  0000123456801011234568            1         81289
6    00001234568  01011234568     27811  0000123456801011234568            2         81289
7    00001234568  01011234568     27811  0000123456801011234568            3         81289
```

Можно ли это сделать как-то попроще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать простой группировкой с трансформацией:

```
df["incident_src"] = df.groupby("check_string")["incident"].transform("first")
```

тогда df будет:

```
    from    to          incident    check_string        occurrences incident_src
npp                     
1   1234567 1011234567  12345       123456701011234567  1           12345
2   1234567 1011234567  45678       123456701011234567  2           12345
3   1234567 1011234567  45678       123456701011234567  3           12345
4   1234567 1011234567  45678       123456701011234567  4           12345
5   1234568 1011234568  81289       123456801011234568  1           81289
6   1234568 1011234568  27811       123456801011234568  2           81289
7   1234568 1011234568  27811       123456801011234568  3           81289
```

Думаю, нужно отметить, что такой способ работает, если вы уверены, что ваш `occurrences` отсортирован по возрастанию. Если нет, то можно подстраховаться как-то так:

```
df["incident_src"] = df.sort_values(["check_string","occurrences"]).groupby("check_string")["incident"].transform("first")
```

Результат, соответственно, будет такой же.